# Regular Expression to get substrings in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I need help with the regular expression. I have 1000's of lines in a file with the following format:

```
 + + [COMPILED]\SRC\FileCheck.cs                               - TotalLine:   99 RealLine:   27 Braces:   18 Comment:   49 Empty:    5
 + + [COMPILED]\SRC\FindstringinFile.cpp                                  - TotalLine:  103 RealLine:   26 Braces:   22 Comment:   50 Empty:    5
 + + [COMPILED]\SRC\findingstring.js                                - TotalLine:   91 RealLine:   22 Braces:   14 Comment:   48 Empty:    7
 + + [COMPILED]\SRC\restinpeace.h                      - TotalLine:   95 RealLine:   24 Braces:   16 Comment:   48 Empty:    7
 + + [COMPILED]\SRC\Getsomething.h++                               - TotalLine:  168 RealLine:   62 Braces:   34 Comment:   51 Empty:   21
 + + [COMPILED]\SRC\MemDataStream.hh                             - TotalLine:  336 RealLine:  131 Braces:   82 Comment:   72 Empty:   51
 + + [CONTEXT]\SRC\MemDataStream.sql                             - TotalLine:  36 RealLine:  138 Braces:   80 Comment:   76 Empty:   59
```

I need a regular expression that can give me:

- FilePath i.e. **\SRC\FileMap.cpp**
- Extension i.e. **.cpp**
- RealLine value i.e. **17**

I'm using PowerShell to implement this and been successful in getting the results back using Get-Content (to read the file) and Select-String cmdlets.
Problem is its taking a long time to get the various substrings and then writing those in the xml file.(I have not put in the code for generating and xml).
I've never used regular expressions before but I know using a regular expression would be an efficient way to get the strings..

Help would be appreciated.

The Select-String cmdlet accepts the regular expression to search for the string.

Current code is as follows:

```
    function Get-SubString
    {
        Param ([string]$StringtoSearch, [string]$StartOfTheString, [string]$EndOfTheString)
        If($StringtoSearch.IndexOf($StartOfTheString) -eq -1 )
        {
            return
        }

        [int]$StartOfIndex = $StringtoSearch.IndexOf($StartOfTheString) + $StartOfTheString.Length
        [int]$EndOfIndex = $StringtoSearch.IndexOf($EndOfTheString , $StartOfIndex)
        if( $StringtoSearch.IndexOf($StartOfTheString)-ne -1 -and $StringtoSearch.IndexOf($EndOfTheString) -eq -1 )
        {
         [string]$ExtractedString=$StringtoSearch.Substring($StartOfTheString.Length)
        }
        else
        {
        [string]$ExtractedString = $StringtoSearch.Substring($StartOfIndex, $EndOfIndex - $StartOfIndex)
        }
        Return $ExtractedString

    }

   function Get-FileExtension
   {
      Param ( [string]$Path)
      [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($Path)
   }


 #For each file extension we will be searching all lines starting with + +
  $SearchIndividualLines = "+ + ["
   $TotalLines = select-string -Pattern $SearchIndividualLines -Path   
   $StandardOutputFilePath -allmatches -SimpleMatch

  for($i = $TotalLines.GetLowerBound(0); $i -le $TotalLines.GetUpperBound(0); $i++)

{
$FileDetailsString = $TotalLines[$i]
#Get File Path
$StartStringForFilePath = "]"

  $EndStringforFilePath =  "- TotalLine"

   $FilePathValue = Get-SubString -StringtoSearch $FileDetailsString -StartOfTheString $StartStringForFilePath -EndOfTheString $EndStringforFilePath

  #Write-Host FilePathValue is $FilePathValue

  #GetFileExtension
  $FileExtensionValue = Get-FileExtension -Path $FilePathValue
  #Write-Host FileExtensionValue is $FileExtensionValue

  #GetRealLine
  $StartStringForRealLine = "RealLine:"
  $EndStringforRealLine =  "Braces"
     $RealLineValue = Get-SubString -StringtoSearch $FileDetailsString -
     StartOfTheString $StartStringForRealLine -EndOfTheString $EndStringforRealLine
  if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($RealLineValue))
  {
  continue
  }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assume you have those in C:\temp\sample.txt

Something like this?

```
PS> (get-content C:\temp\sample.txt) | % { if ($_ -match '.*COMPILED\](\\.*)(\.\w+)\s*.*RealLine:\s*(\d+).*') { [PSCustomObject]@{FilePath=$matches[1]; Extention=$Matches[2]; RealLine=$matches[3]} } }

FilePath              Extention RealLine
--------              --------- --------
\SRC\FileCheck        .cs       27      
\SRC\FindstringinFile .cpp      26      
\SRC\findingstring    .js       22      
\SRC\restinpeace      .h        24      
\SRC\Getsomething     .h        62      
\SRC\MemDataStream    .hh       131
```

**Update:**
Stuff inside paranthesis is captured, so if you want to capture [COMPILED], you will need to just need to add that part into the regex:

Instead of

```
$_ -match '.*COMPILED\](\\.*)
```

use

```
$_ -match '.*(\[COMPILED\]\\.*)
```

The link in the comment to your question includes a good primer on the regex.

**UPDATE 2**
Now that you want to capture set of path, I am guessing you sample looks like this:

```
+ + [COMPILED]C:\project\Rom\Main\Plan\file1.file2.file3\Cmd\Camera.culture.less-Lat‌​e-PP.min.js    - TotalLine:  336 RealLine:  131 Braces:   82 Comment:   72 Empty:   51
```

The technique above will work, you just need to do a very slight adjustment for the first parenthesis like this:

```
$_ -match (\[COMPILED\].*)
```

This will tell regex that you want to capture [COMPILED] and everything that comes after it, until

```
(\.\w+)
```

i.e to the extension, which as a dot and a couple of letters (which might not works if you had an extension like .3gp)

So, your original one liner would instead be:

```
(get-content C:\temp\sample.txt) | % { if ($_ -match '.(\[COMPILED\].*)(\.\w+)\s*.*RealLine:\s*(\d+).*') { [PSCustomObject]@{FilePath=$matches[1]; Extention=$Matches[2]; RealLine=$matches[3]} } }
```

Comment: Thanks Adil.. this is perfect!!

Comment: Can you edit it so that it can return the full path too like this:-

Comment: can u edit this so that it can return this full path like this [COMPILED]C:\project\Rom\Main\Plan\file1.file2.file3\Cmd\Camera.culture.less-Late-PP.min.js

Comment: and i still want the extension in file path and seperately too can u help?

Comment: Hey @a6k006, it is pretty easy to do. Al you have to do is expand the limits of first parenthesis.

Comment: what do u mean by extending the limits.. how to do it?

Comment: @a6k006 Take a look at the update2 I posted yesterday that explains it